# ZooKeeperServer doesnot exists in org.apache.zookeeper.server which is been imported from org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:jar:3.4.0

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

ZooKeeperServer doesnot exists in org.apache.zookeeper.server  which is been imported from org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:jar:3.4.0

Any alternatives for this?

I checked the dependency hierarchy zookeeper jar is still existing and not been completely removed by apache kafka

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-server-common:jar:3.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-group-coordinator:jar:3.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-metadata:jar:3.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-raft:jar:3.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-storage:jar:3.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-storage-api:jar:3.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:jar:2.13.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.13.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:jar:0.7.9:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-collection-compat_2.12:jar:2.6.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:jar:1.0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.12.15:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:jar:3.9.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.6.3:runtime
```

Comment: I added the dependency explicitly for time being as its no longer present in the jar coming from kafka_2.12
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I added the dependency explicitly for time being as its no longer present in the jar coming from `kafka_2.12`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
    <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`kafka_2.12` is the server package, and should not be used for Kafka clients. You only need `kafka-clients` dependency unless you are trying to run some type of integration testing against Kafka brokers.

As of Kafka Kraft mode release, it no longer requires Zookeeper.

Comment: yes,It is required for integration testing

Comment: You can try Testcontainers or EmbeddedKafka from spring-kafka-test instead for this